# Pass SQL to Report Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, reporting

How do I pass a `SQL Query` from `C#` to `Report Server 2008 R2`?

I need to generate a `SQL` statement from `C#` dynamically and have it display data in a report using `Report Server`.

I already declared a `parameter` and `dataset` for the report in `Report Server`. Now I am able to pass the `parameter` from `C#` but I also want to **pass `SQL Query` from `C#` to `Report Server`**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show all relevant code.. this will help in having others answer your question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't very secure you could pass the SQL statement to a text field parameter in the report.  Then you could pass that statement as a parameter to a stored procedure in SQL Server (assuming you use that).  Then you could use sp_executesql to execute the statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

One issue you may have with this is that the Report Server is going to expect a standard set of columns in your dataset so you will want the statement you pass to have a standard set of columns.  I don't think that reports can handle dynamic fields without a lot of trickery.

One thing we've done to handle "dynamic" columns is have the statement return "field_1", "field_2", etc as the result set and then map your report to those generic columns.